# VNC only displaying the mouse cursor but nothing else

Tags: raspberry-pi, x11, vnc-server

I have a RaspberryPi with Raspbian and `x11vnc` installed. I can:

- `startx &`
- `x11vnc -usepw -background`

And then connect to the VNC Server using my Mac. However, after some event (it used to work at some point), the VNC Server only displays a black screen.

I can connect to the RPI using SSH but I can't attach a screen at the moment, because I don't have one.

How do I get the X11vnc Server to display the actual screen again?

The output when I start the server

```
03/02/2014 18:38:59 -usepw: found /home/pi/.vnc/passwd
03/02/2014 18:38:59 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 5589
03/02/2014 18:38:59 XOpenDisplay("") failed.
03/02/2014 18:38:59 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
03/02/2014 18:38:59 
03/02/2014 18:38:59 *** XOpenDisplay failed. No -display or DISPLAY.
03/02/2014 18:38:59 *** Trying ":0" in 4 seconds.  Press Ctrl-C to abort.
03/02/2014 18:38:59 *** 1 2 
3 4 
03/02/2014 18:39:03 *** XOpenDisplay of ":0" successful.
03/02/2014 18:39:03 
03/02/2014 18:39:03 Using X display :0
03/02/2014 18:39:03 rootwin: 0x43 reswin: 0xa00001 dpy: 0xe86250
03/02/2014 18:39:03 
03/02/2014 18:39:03 ------------------ USEFUL INFORMATION ------------------
03/02/2014 18:39:03 X DAMAGE available on display, using it for polling hints.
03/02/2014 18:39:03   To disable this behavior use: '-noxdamage'
03/02/2014 18:39:03 
03/02/2014 18:39:03   Most compositing window managers like 'compiz' or 'beryl'
03/02/2014 18:39:03   cause X DAMAGE to fail, and so you may not see any screen
03/02/2014 18:39:03   updates via VNC.  Either disable 'compiz' (recommended) or
03/02/2014 18:39:03   supply the x11vnc '-noxdamage' command line option.
03/02/2014 18:39:03 
03/02/2014 18:39:03 Wireframing: -wireframe mode is in effect for window moves.
03/02/2014 18:39:03   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
03/02/2014 18:39:03   errors, etc) it may be disabled:
03/02/2014 18:39:03    - use '-nowf' to disable wireframing completely.
03/02/2014 18:39:03    - use '-nowcr' to disable the Copy Rectangle after the
03/02/2014 18:39:03      moved window is released in the new position.
03/02/2014 18:39:03   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
03/02/2014 18:39:03   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to 
03/02/2014 18:39:03   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
03/02/2014 18:39:03   periodic repaints.
03/02/2014 18:39:03 
03/02/2014 18:39:03 XFIXES available on display, resetting cursor mode
03/02/2014 18:39:03   to: '-cursor most'.
03/02/2014 18:39:03   to disable this behavior use: '-cursor arrow'
03/02/2014 18:39:03   or '-noxfixes'.
03/02/2014 18:39:03 using XFIXES for cursor drawing.
03/02/2014 18:39:03 GrabServer control via XTEST.
03/02/2014 18:39:03 
03/02/2014 18:39:03 Scroll Detection: -scrollcopyrect mode is in effect to
03/02/2014 18:39:03   use RECORD extension to try to detect scrolling windows
03/02/2014 18:39:03   (induced by either user keystroke or mouse input).
03/02/2014 18:39:03   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
03/02/2014 18:39:03   errors, etc) it may be disabled via: '-noscr'
03/02/2014 18:39:03   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
03/02/2014 18:39:03   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to 
03/02/2014 18:39:03   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
03/02/2014 18:39:03   periodic repaints.
03/02/2014 18:39:03 
03/02/2014 18:39:03 XKEYBOARD: number of keysyms per keycode 7 is greater
03/02/2014 18:39:03   than 4 and 51 keysyms are mapped above 4.
03/02/2014 18:39:03   Automatically switching to -xkb mode.
03/02/2014 18:39:03   If this makes the key mapping worse you can
03/02/2014 18:39:03   disable it with the "-noxkb" option.
03/02/2014 18:39:03   Also, remember "-remap DEAD" for accenting characters.
03/02/2014 18:39:03 
03/02/2014 18:39:03 X FBPM extension not supported.
03/02/2014 18:39:03 X display is capable of DPMS.
03/02/2014 18:39:03 --------------------------------------------------------
03/02/2014 18:39:03 
03/02/2014 18:39:03 Default visual ID: 0x21
03/02/2014 18:39:04 Read initial data from X display into framebuffer.
03/02/2014 18:39:04 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 16/16/2272
03/02/2014 18:39:04 
03/02/2014 18:39:04 X display :0 is 16bpp depth=16 true color
03/02/2014 18:39:04 
03/02/2014 18:39:04 Autoprobing TCP port 
03/02/2014 18:39:04 Autoprobing selected TCP port 5900
03/02/2014 18:39:04 Autoprobing TCP6 port 
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:04 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 Failure autoprobing: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 listen6: socket: Address family not supported by protocol
03/02/2014 18:39:05 (Ignore the above error if this system is IPv4-only.)
03/02/2014 18:39:05 Not listening on IPv6 interface.
03/02/2014 18:39:05 
03/02/2014 18:39:05 Xinerama is present and active (e.g. multi-head).
03/02/2014 18:39:05 Xinerama: number of sub-screens: 1
03/02/2014 18:39:05 Xinerama: no blackouts needed (only one sub-screen)
03/02/2014 18:39:05 
03/02/2014 18:39:05 fb read rate: 362 MB/sec
03/02/2014 18:39:05 fast read: reset -wait  ms to: 10
03/02/2014 18:39:05 fast read: reset -defer ms to: 10
03/02/2014 18:39:05 The X server says there are 10 mouse buttons.
03/02/2014 18:39:05 screen setup finished.
03/02/2014 18:39:05 

The VNC desktop is:      raspberrypi:0
PORT=5900

******************************************************************************
Have you tried the x11vnc '-ncache' VNC client-side pixel caching feature yet?

The scheme stores pixel data offscreen on the VNC viewer side for faster
retrieval.  It should work with any VNC viewer.  Try it by running:

    x11vnc -ncache 10 ...

One can also add -ncache_cr for smooth 'copyrect' window motion.
More info: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-client-caching
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was probably caused by me starting another `startx` session.

I forgot that I configured my Pi to boot into the Desktop using `raspi-config`.

So now I start the X11vnc session as follows via an SSH terminal:

```
x11vnc -bg -forever -nevershare -usepw -rfbport 5900
```

And it works again:

[image]

Comment: I did the same and still go the black screen :(